# Why sabres replaced swords after middle age

Tags: europe, warfare, weapons

After the middle age sabres almost completely replaced swords in the europe. I don't see any reason why sabres are superior to swords used before so why that happened?

By swords used before I mean the straight blades which enabled to cut and thrust equally well (rapiers are mostly for thrusting).

The "sabre" idea came to the Europe from the east where curved blades were widely used . Polish and Hungary fought with tatars and found out that curved blades are very effective for raiders(cavalry) when fighting unarmored enemy but I wonder if that was the only reason to replace straight swords (not rapiers).

Comment: But sabres are a type of sword...

Comment: invention of gunpowder enabled the use of lighter cold weapons since general killing capacity remained the same

Comment: What research have  you done?

Comment: What's your reference for making the statement that sabres replaced swords?

Comment: Strictly a guess here with no research whatsoever... generally speaking a "sword" (such as a broadsword) was a stand up weapon, used by a knight, to hew off an opponents head, arms, whatever. A large sword was not the normal weapon of choice from a mounted position. Once the combatants became mounted forces charging one another in great numbers (aka cavalry), the switch to the (generally curved) saber form was met. The curved form meant for easier wearing in a seated position, and easier use without the casual lopping off of horse ears. (Unless of course, that is your 'thing')

Comment: Also, I'm not sure I agree with the reasoning behind the question anyway. During the Napoleonic era, stabbing implements were used in greater numbers than slashing. The epee form was used by the elite of France at about the same time as the muskets become more prevalent. If the question was changed to reflect a change in the straight blade form giving way to the curved I'd have less issues with the fact that the saber **is** a sword.